# How to control order of execution of workflow

Tags: workflow, order-of-execution

How can I control order of execution of separate workflow rules?

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer

Workflow rules execute "simultaneously," and therefore have no defined order.

### Long Answer

Workflow rules are evaluated in arbitrary order, and for each one that matches, its actions are queued for execution. Then, all queued actions execute. Finally, if any workflow rule requested a re-evaluation on record update, and the record was updated, then the process begins anew, up to five times. Through each round of execution, all rules evaluate against the same version of the record, and so effectively act as if they were running in parallel/simultaneously, and any field updates that touch the same field within the same round will have an undefined behavior.

It is possible to "control" the order by using workflow rule recursion. One workflow rule can update a field and request another round of execution, and another workflow rule can detect that change and do something else. This has a few problems, including the fact that if the field being changed is already set to the value that the field would be set to, then no update occurs, and the recursion does not happen.

For this reason, we've been given the Process Builder. We can now define an entire process, which is like a bundle of workflow rules, which we can control as we like, and even chain one process to another, allowing reusable bundles of rules. Salesforce.com encourages us to use this newer technology because it is more powerful and flexible than workflow rules, although it still tends to perform poorly when dealing with bulk data loads. If an admin needs to define rules that operate in a certain order, however, they'll most likely want to use Process Builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to try, the only thing you can do is check in the workflow if the previous one has completed.

For example, if you have a workflow to update the status of a case to "new email" whenever a new email message record is associated to that case, you would then have a workflow on case that says "if the status of this case is changed to new email, do x y z"

This is the closest youre going to get to controlling the order of workflows.

If you have 2 workflows on a single object that both fire in the same save operation, you can't control the order of execution.

For instance, if you have 2 workflows that fire when case status is changed to "new email", there is no guarantee which workflow would fire first.

This is the simplest answer. If you get SUPER creative you might be able to make it work when you move away from workflows. For instance, process builder offers multiple branches of logic and process builder can call **flows** directly. Flows are much more advanced and can do some pretty cool stuff. Chances are if you investigate process builder and flows you can solve your problem without needing to control the order of execution.